# The assembly '..\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\bf3fce1a\adf83866\App_GlobalResources.dll' is already loaded in another appdomain

Tags: 2010, asp.net, iis7

[image]we have intranet web application and deployed farm solutions, when we open any farm solution pages that resides n _layouts/eservices/empquery.aspx sometimes pages opened and get the data from sql and some times when we refresh or click again the same page it show below error.

> The assembly
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\bf3fce1a\adf83866\App_GlobalResources.dll' is already
>   loaded in another appdomain. Setting <deployment retail="true"
>   /> in machine.config can help solve this issue.  Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: The assembly
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\bf3fce1a\adf83866\App_GlobalResources.dll' is already
>   loaded in another appdomain. Setting <deployment retail="true"
>   /> in machine.config can help solve this issue.

Note: we disable debug=false in web .config and at machine level

> <deployment retail="true" /> Event code: 3005  Event message: An
>   unhandled exception has occurred.  Event time: 23/11/1437 02:16:17 ص 
>   Event time (UTC): 22/11/1437 11:16:17 م  Event ID:
>   8663b1247e284146bc926815058403cb  Event sequence: 77  Event
>   occurrence: 1  Event detail code: 0    Application information: 
>       Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/838794701/ROOT-11-131166405578384075 
>       Trust level: WSS_Minimal 
>       Application Virtual Path: / 
>       Application Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80\ 
>       Machine name: XXXXSPDV01    Process information: 
>       Process ID: 6204 
>       Process name: w3wp.exe 
>       Account name: XXXX\spfarm    Exception information: 
>       Exception type: HttpException 
>       Exception message: The assembly 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\bf3fce1a\adf83866\App_GlobalResources.dll' is already
>   loaded in another appdomain. Setting  in
>   machine.config can help solve this issue.    Request information: 
>       Request URL: http://extranet.xxxx.xxxx/Style Library/images/fonts/gesstextlight-light.ttf 
>       Request path: /Style Library/images/fonts/gesstextlight-light.ttf 
>       User host address: 10.179.5.4 
>       User:
>       Is authenticated: False 
>       Authentication Type:
>       Thread account name: XXXX\spfarm    Thread information: 
>       Thread ID: 18 
>       Thread account name: XXXX\spfarm 
>       Is impersonating: False 
>       Stack trace:    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ReportTopLevelCompilationException()
>   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled()
>   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallAppInitializeMethod()    at
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)

Custom event details: